# Python Selective Copy Homework Assistance

Tags: python

> Selective Copy:
>
> Write a program that walks through a folder tree and searches for
> files with a certain file extension (such as .pdf or .jpg). Copy these
> files from whatever location they are into a new folder.

I keep getting a traceback error as seen in [this screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9l61m.png).

I do not know what I am doing wrong.

This is the code I have:

```
import os, shutil, sys

def selective_copy(src_folder: str = None, ext: str = None, dest_folder: str = None) -> None:
    if src_folder is None:
        raise AttributeError('src_folder must be given.')
    if ext is None:
        raise AttributeError('.jpg')
    if dest_folder is None:
        raise AttributeError('dest_folder must be given.')
    src_folder = os.path.abspath(src_folder)
    os.chdir(src_folder)
    os.mkdir(dest_folder)
    # Walk through a folder tree
    for foldername, subfolders, filenames in os.walk("./"):
        print("Looking in folder: %s..." % foldername)
         # Find files with a specific extension
        for filename in filenames:
            if filename.endswith('.jpg'):
                 # Copy files to a new folder
                print("Copying file: %s..." % filename)
                shutil.copy(filename, dest_folder)
    print("Done.")



def main():
    selective_copy('../', '.jpg', 'new_folder')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: What is unclear about the error? `new_folder`  already exists, so change your `dest_folder` parameter in the main function

Comment: You could check the documentation for `os.mkdir` to see that it may throw an exception if that folder already exists.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour]. SO is a Q&A site, so what's your question? Please read [How to ask and answer homework questions](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/334822/4518341). See also [ask].

Comment: The error message means that the directory `new_folder` already exists. If you look at [`os.makedirs()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.makedirs), there might be a parameter you can use to avoid the exception. Or you could use a `try`-`except` to catch `FileExistsError`s.

Answer (score -1):

Instead of `os.mkdir()`, I would suggest looking at `os.makedirs()` ([documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.makedirs)). It has a parameter that I believe you'll find useful for this situation.